# TS2339: Property 'msMatchesSelector' does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: typescript

I was facing the problem that my application was showing the error `Object doesn't support the property or method 'matches'` in IE, which is why I added the following to my `polyfills.ts` file:

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
    Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;
}
```

However, after upgrading from angular6 to angular7 (or more likely because I updated the typescript module to 3.1.3), I'm now getting the error

> TS2339: Property 'msMatchesSelector' does not exist on type 'Element'

when building the app. What is the problem?

Comment: Were you able to fix this ?

Comment: Yes, I created a file `dom.ie.d.ts` in the src directory with the following content: `interface Element {
    msMatchesSelector(selectors: string): boolean;
}`.